# How to generate or set unique name (using current Date) for daily backup SSAS Cubes

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssas, cube

I have an ETL with an Analysis Services Execute DDL object running a daily backup of my cube the XML code below:

```
<Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine"><Object><DatabaseID>MyCube</DatabaseID></Object><File>B:\Backups\Cubes\MyCube.abf</File><AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite></Backup>
```

So I'm getting every day a file like:

```
MyCube.abf
```

And using SSIS with Sql task object or Sql server agent, I would like to have an unique file for every day with the current date.
Something Like:

```
MyCube_2018_05_09.abf
MyCube_2018_05_10.abf
MyCube_2018_05_11.abf
```

Also If can set something to delete the oldest backup leaving the recent 2 weeks that would be really helpful.

Note:
I had referenced the website below, but I tried several time in different ways and nothing work.

http://dbatasks.blogspot.com/2012/08/taking-backup-of-ssas-database.html

Any assistance in this regard will be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: IN SSIS are you using a variable for the file name?  If so you can use the Expressions to build out the date

Comment: In Expression Builder:  "FileName_"+ (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) +  RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY( GETDATE()), 2) + ".csv"

Comment: I posted answer for building your file name, deleting the backups would be a separate question/separate process.  and thanks @billinkc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moved to answer:

In Expression Builder in SSIS for variable you can copy/paste this and tweak it a bit for your needs.  This puts year as 4 digits, and months and days as 2 with leading 0's if its a single number day or month:

```
"MyCube_"+ (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) +  RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY( GETDATE()), 2) + ".abf"
```

Comment: Ok, let me try.

Comment: If you have a path you will have to add that to the above as well to get full filename/path and then use that variable in your save file functionality as filename

Comment: how I'm I supposed to put the variable into my XMLA code below: <Backup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine"><Object><DatabaseID>MyCube</DatabaseID></Object><File>B:\Backups\Cubes\MyCube.abf</File><AllowOverwrite>true</AllowOverwrite></Backup>